# Extract value from json response python?

Tags: python

I am making a request to an endpoint and getting a json response in the following format.

```
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())

{"context":"product=fhvh, price=25,product=vfjvnf,price=37,product=fvfv,price=3.....}
```

I want to loop over them and get the count of the products that have a price point of more than 22.

How can i get that? I tried to loop over the json response initially but i don't believe that will work due to the format of the output. Is there a better solution? How can i convert the response to maybe a dict or tuple first? Can someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the structure of the response? Can you provide the skeleton?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Yes, i have. This is the skeleton :- 
```{"context":"product=fhvh, price=25,product=vfjvnf,price=37,product=fvfv,price=3.....}```

Comment: Do you know if it always comes in pairs? `product=fhvh, price=25`

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Yes, it always comes in pairs.

Comment: It looks like this question is more about string processing rather than JSON.

Comment: Are the products all unique?

Comment: @RichardDodson Yes, they are all unique.

Comment: So your response is coming in as an unordered ordered list within a string with no validation (e.g. product=fhvh, etc.)? Can you just post the actual JSON?

Comment: @psychopg2 Unfortunately this the actual data that i am getting.

Comment: I've a solution but its not an ideal or one I'd personally use

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Can you share it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the worst possible solution, it relies on the response always has a `product` and a `price` and can be very unreliable.

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

context=data.get('context')
elements = context.split(',')
chunks=[elements[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(elements), 2)]
print(chunks)
```

```
[['product=fhvh', ' price=25'], ['product=vfjvnf', 'price=37'], ['product=fvfv', 'price=3']]
```

I'd look into data processing libraries used by Big Data like Pandas that might have a more reliable way to doing it.

## Update

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

context=data.get('context')
elements = context.split(',')
chunks=[elements[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(elements), 2)]
print(chunks)

product_list = []
for item in chunks:
     obj1=item[0].split('=')
     obj2=item[1].split('=')
     product = { obj1[0].strip(): obj1[1].strip(), obj2[0].strip(): float(obj2[1].strip())}
     product_list.append(product)

print(product_list)

for product in product_list:
     if product.get('price') > 22.0:
             print(product)
```

Comment: Hmmm, so you converted it into smaller lists. How can i get the product whose price is more than 22?

Comment: It does always have a price and product.

Comment: It's an array of arrays... so you can just iterate and build another array that has elements that are over a certain price.

Comment: Yes, as long as the response provides it in that sort of order. So if the response dos this `product=fhvh, product=vfjvnf, price=25, price=37` you're screwed.

Comment: This is why its very unreliable, you're putting faith in the API to always be consistent

Comment: Well i will still accept this as a potential answer and will look into pandas.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever check the update, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the payload you have isn't JSON but some alternative format. My advice would be to convert each entry in `context` into an object:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = float(price)

def parse_data(resp):

    # First, read in the JSON
    raw_data = r.json()
 
    # Next, split the context field in the JSON into a list-of-tuples
    # where each item represents a key and value.
    parsed_data = [tuple(item.strip().split('=')) for item in raw_data["context"].split(',')]
   
    # Finally, convert each product to our type and return the list of them
    # This assumes that the payload contains a product followed by a price
    return [Product([i][1], y[i + 1][1]) for i in range(0, len(y), 2)]

r = requests.get(url)
filtered = [product for product in parse_data(r) if product.price > 22]
```

This code obeys separation of concerns and produces the output you want (all products with a price greater than 22). That being said, this relies heavily on assumptions about what is returned from the API you're requesting. You'll want to add data checks to ensure that you're not getting bad data.

Comment: This looks much better than mine, but I'd parse the price as a `float`. It may have decimals.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I think that's a valid point. Actually, I don't think I did any parsing of the value at all.